# pop up box in cdata xml tags

Tags: xml, xhtml, cdata, popupwindow

I'm trying to load a pop up window within xml cdata tags but not getting any luck,

This is my code on the filename.xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pagesettings>
<record>    

<bgColor>0x000000</bgColor>
<bgTransparency>80</bgTransparency>
<horizPosition>right</horizPosition> <!-- possible values: left; right -->
<htmlContent>
<en>
<![CDATA[       
<p></p><p class="mainTitle">TITLE HERE</p><p>    </p>
<p>CONTENT HERE</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<A HREF="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/media/logo.jpg"></A>

<p>&nbsp;</p>   
]]>         
</en>       
</htmlContent>
</record>   
</pagesettings>
```

The logo works fine , an image appears and once you click it it goes to the link.
I want to convert that href link into a pop up window.

For example i want google.com in a pop up window 250x250 how would i go about this remembering that it is xhtml and cdata tags.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML and CDATA raise no particular challenges here. You can't put a `<![CDATA[` section inside another `<![CDATA[` section, but since you don't need to include a `<` or `&` character in your script, you have no need to. eg.:

```
<htmlContent><en><![CDATA[       
    <p class="mainTitle">TITLE HERE</p>
    <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="popup"><img src="images/media/logo.jpg" alt="Google"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('popup').onclick= function() {
            return !window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=250,height=250');
        };
    </script>
]]></en></htmlContent>
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted that code replacing old cdata tags but once uploaded to ftp test folder it shows up as this...

CLICK TO SEE IMAGE http://i55.tinypic.com/2r6ofia.jpg

Comment: It looks like whatever you are using to parse the HTML doesn't support the `<script>` element. If you are generating HTML for the browser, then you'll need to fix that. If you are using a rendering engine that just doesn't support `<script>` then you're probably stuck.

Comment: I figured i can't embed a flash mp3 player within this code and now not even a pop is a viable solution :( .... so there is no way possible for a pop up to work...jquery would not work as that requires script too

Comment: What *is* it that's displaying the HTML here? If there's no JavaScript support in it, the only remaining approach is `<a target="_blank">`, but then even that might not be supported...

Comment: What do you mean, the site is a dynamic xml driven site, so site is in flash but contents of the site is edited via xml files. and i've edited the code so now it just opens up in a new window adding target="_blank" but the pop up still does not work it comes up with all the writing...

Comment: Whatever you write has got to be supported by the Flash application. Edit the Flash application itself to do what you want. (Or write a website in real HTML)

Comment: I'm no expert on Flash so would not have a clue how to edit and what values to place.